# Bootstrap Responsive Option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, grid

I am working on a layout override in Joomla 3 for a job application form. The component is using some Bootstrap already, but not for what I want right now.

The problem I am running into, and not sure if I can solve without modifying the PHP itself, is with the ability to turn on and off different fields and have the layout respond.

So... Right now it's all done in tables, so lots of rows in here. I am trying to get rid of the table layout and change it into something that stacks nicely on mobile.

I'm going to use the first couple of lines as an example. Both lines could possibly contain 3 columns, depending on what fields are being displayed.

First line asks for Name, Middle Name and Last Name. I currently have Middle Name turned off
Second line asks for Phone, Mobile and Work phone numbers.

What I want to do is have that first line display Name and Last name as wide as it can in the space provided so it appears there are only two columns in the grid. However, if I am asked to put the Middle name field back in, I can simply turn it on and it will go back to three columns.

Is this possible with Bootstrap alone, or would this require setting up something like (For example, I'm not a programmer) a series of if/else statements that will change the grid based on the selection of fields.

Hope this all makes sense. Let me know if I was unclear anywhere.

Comment: Posting your code would help. In short, Bootstrap is a CSS framework. Using divs or tables (Bootstrap supports responsive tables) is up to you and both will work. The order and how you generate these will more than likely be in creating a PHP while loop or similar to generate your view. Without seeing your code it's difficult to give more direction.

Comment: If you require to stack the fields on mobile devices, then it may be easier to move it all to divs, and drop the tables altogether.

Comment: I don't want to use tables as I don't want side scrolling, I want the fields to stack on top of each other when in Mobile.

I want to use div. I can use Bootstrap and set it up easy enough, the problem is the PHP (Again, it's a component, I didn't write it and I'm not a programmer).

Please read the original posts about the columns, this is what I'm asking about. How to change from a 3 column grid to a 2 column grid if one of the fields is not enabled on the backend and changing back to 3 column if it's enabled again.

Can I do this with Bootstrap only or are PHP mods required?